# only on macOS Sierra: library not found for -lAFNetworking

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, macos-sierra

when building on macOS Sierra, I get the error

```
ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
```

On El Capitan, everything works fine. I tried different Xcode versions on Sierra, 7 and 8 - both times the same error. Does anyone know what the reason could be?

Answer (score 0):

May be :

1. Fixed it by linker renaming in Link Binary under the Frameworks group.
2. Delete path except the "$inherited".

   Make a new folder called: "Library" with Finder in the Project root folder (with the AFNetworking files) and than drag the folder to the Library Search Path window. Close Xcode now and re-open, clean and build!
3. Make sure Build Active Architectures Only in your Project/Target are the same. We often set the debug yes and set the release no.